# Passing Data From Pop Because of Applying Filters in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem in passing data from the filter page to the location page. I need to pass data since i'm applying filters. If i want to display a certain location only, that data will be passed to the location page. How would i fix this since it doesn't return to the locations-list.html

> locations-list.html

```
openFilterPage() {
     this.navCtrl.push("FilterPage")
  }
```

> filter.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="By Location" tabIcon="compass"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="By Date" tabIcon="calendar"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> filter-by-location.html

```
<ion-content padding  [formGroup]="filterForm">
    <ion-list formArrayName="rows">
        <button ion-item menuClose (click)="selectLocation('all')"> 
            Show All Location
        </button>
        <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let row of filterForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" (click)="selectLocation(row.value.location)">
            {{ i+ 1}}. &nbsp; {{ row.value.location }}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

> filter-by-location.ts

```
selectLocation(data) {
    data = data || 'No data';

    this.navCtrl.push("LocationsList", {
      data: data
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why do you push to `TourPackagePage` in `filter-by-location.ts`? As my understand, it should be `locations-list` page?

Comment: @Duannx. Yeah. I'm sorry. I edited it. It should be LocationsList

Comment: Since you push back `LocationsList` with the data, you can get the filter data from `navParams`. Did you try it?